Hamiltonian is time independent in rotating frame

A spin 1/2 particle has hamiltonian $H = -\gamma B(t)\cdot S$, where $$B(t) = B_0 \hat z + b(\hat x \cos(\omega t) + \hat y \sin(\omega t)),$$ and $S$ is the spin operator.
Let $| \psi (t) \rangle$ be the particle at time $t $, and define $| \chi (t) \rangle$ by $$| \psi (t) \rangle = U(\omega t \hat z)|\chi (t)\rangle $$ (i.e time dependent rotation of angle $\omega t$ about the $z$-axis).
Show $|\chi (t) \rangle$ obeys TDSE with time-independent Hamiltonian.

I have taken derivative with respect to $t$ to obtain $$ih \frac \partial {\partial t}|\chi (t) \rangle = (U^{-1}HU + J_zU^{-1}U)|\chi (t) \rangle,$$ using the exponential definition for rotation operator.
Now $H$ is a dot product between two vectors, so is rotation invariant, thus $U^{-1}HU = H$. Furthermore, $J_z$ is time independent. So the hamiltonian for $|\chi (t) \rangle$ is $ H + J_z$, the sum of a time dependent operator and a time independent operator, so is time dependent - what am I missing?
I am wondering if I need to account for how the spin operator changes over time / rotations? But I’m not sure how to go about this.


Now $H$ is a dot product between two vectors, so is rotation invariant,

Hold your horses! It is not so simple. The magnetic field is a vector, but in this case it behaves like a scalar operator [1] (i.e., invariant under the operation of rotation operator), so you should calculate it carefully. Generally, external magnetic fields breaks rotational symmetry (think about induced magnetization, in a paramagnetic system, for example).
We could show (using Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) that
$$
U^{-1}S_xU = S_x \cos(\omega t) -S_y\sin(\omega t)
$$
$$
U^{-1}S_yU = S_x\sin(\omega t)+S_y\cos(\omega t)
$$
So we have
$$
U^{-1}HU = B_0S_z + bS_x \neq H.
$$
I think it solves your issue and the rest is correct.

[1] Tensorial Operators wikipedia article
